# Why doesn't my innerHTML method work to list things in my contact form?

Tags: javascript, forms, html-lists, innerhtml

I am making a program, and I'm wondering why all I see on my html page is the form, but only a single . where the bulleted list for an unordered list should be.  I input the user input in the fields, but it doesn't show me the data in the fields, like it's supposed to, when I click submit.  Here's the code.

```
function getFormElements() {
    var gather_form_elements = new Array(
        $("#first_name").val(), 
        $("#last_name").val(),
        $("email").val(), 
        $("#phone_number").val()
    );

    displayValues(gather_form_elements);
}

function displayValues(gather_form_elements) {

    for(i=0; i<gather_form_elements.length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("contact_info").innerHTML = "<li>" + gather_form_elements[i] + "</li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I should also point out that I'm using this jQuery to make the button call the first function:  $(document).ready(function(){

     $("button").click(function()
    {
        getFormElements();
    });

});

Answer (score 1):

Because you are overiding it on every iteration. Try to accumulate the html before using `innerHTML` like this:

```
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i < gather_form_elements.length; i++) {
    html += "<li>" + gather_form_elements[i] + "</li>";
//       ^^ the += is crucial. If you don't use it, it will just replace the content of html (the innerHTML in your code), we need to use += to append to html instead of overriding it.
}
document.getElementById("contact_info").innerHTML = html;
```

You can acheive the same result using only one line of code:

```
document.getElementById("contact_info").innerHTML =
    '<li>' + gather_form_elements.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  It looks like it's still doing the same thing.  Looking at your code, it looks like all that's doing is creating a variable, and giving it a new value on each iteration.  It looks like it's doing the same thing(overriding) on every iteration.

Comment: @JustinRoohparvar No, it is not the same thing. In my version I'm using `+=` instead of `=`. If you replace `=` with `+=` in your code it will work. I just accumulated the `html` before using `innerHTML` so we won't use a lot of times and cause overhead. It's as I point out in the comment `+=` is crucial.

Comment: I just used your shorter join version, and that works.  However, now what it's doing is flashing on the screen(the correct data in a list), but it's disappearing immediately.

Comment: @JustinRoohparvar probably you are using the `innerHTML` somewhere else.

Comment: No sir, that's the only place.  The code that I put up is what I have.

Comment: @JustinRoohparvar the short version doesn't need a loop. Did you put it in the loop above?

Comment: No.  This is how it looks now:  function getFormElements() {
    var gather_form_elements = new Array(
        $("#first_name").val(), 
        $("#last_name").val(),
        $("email").val(), 
        $("#phone_number").val()
    );

    displayValues(gather_form_elements);
}

function displayValues(gather_form_elements) {

   document.getElementById("contact_info").innerHTML =
    '<li>' + gather_form_elements.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
}

Comment: function getFormElements() { var gather_form_elements = new Array( 
    $("#first_name").val(), $("#last_name").val(), $("email").val(), 
    $("#phone_number").val() ); displayValues(gather_form_elements); } 
    function displayValues(gather_form_elements) { 
    document.getElementById("contact_info").innerHTML = '<li>' + 
    gather_form_elements.join('</li><li>') + '</li>'; }